# Why is there a space generated when i split the string using /W

Tags: ruby

I am trying to split a string to get the words on it..

My code is as follows:

```
def words(string)
    string.downcase!
    hash_str = Hash.new
    string.split(/\W/i).each {|y| 
      if(hash_str.has_key?(y)) 
         hash_str[y] += 1
      else 
         hash_str[y] =1
      end
    }
    return hash_str
end

hash_t = words("A man, a plan, a canal -- Panama")
hash_t.each{|x,y| puts "#{x}:#{y}"}
```

And the output is:

```
1    :5
2   a:3  
3  plan:1
4  man:1
5  canal:1
6  panama:1
```

My problem is it seems that the whitespace is also being counted. 
How can I add in /W the whitespace?

Thank you.

Comment: maybe u can try use `split(/\b/)`

Comment: Works For Me. `hash_t` is `{"a"=>3, "man"=>1, ""=>5, "plan"=>1, "canal"=>1, "panama"=>1}`. What Ruby are you using?

Comment: i'm using this -> http://codepad.org/hXroGsk4

Comment: Oh, I thought you were complaining about the space before `a:3`. Which is absent.

Comment: i just don't know why there is :5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blank-string entries are coming where two or more non-word characters are adjacent.

So `"A man, a"` splits at the space to give `"A"` and `"man, a"`; then at the comma to give `"man"` and `" a"`, then at the space again to give `""` and `"a"`.

If you used `split(/\W+/i)`, you'd get what you expect, because it would treat each string of non-word characters as a single split.

[Codepad link](http://codepad.org/2TVCdqNJ)

Comment: oh... i never thought that "" is also counted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it is conceptually more natural to use `scan`. A typical implementation of this use case would be this:

```
def words(string)
  Hash.new(0).tap{|h| string.downcase.scan(/\w+/){|w| h[w] += 1}}
end

words("A man, a plan, a canal -- Panama").each{|x,y| puts "#{x}:#{y}"}
```

which would give:

```
a:3
man:1
plan:1
canal:1
panama:1
```

Answer (score 1):

A more Ruby-ish solution:

```
str = "A man, a plan, a canal -- Panama"
str.downcase.split(/\W+/).inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }

=> {"plan"=>1, "a"=>3, "panama"=>1, "man"=>1, "canal"=>1}
```

Comment: that's a clean code.. guess i'm not yet used to Ruby. :) Thank you :)

Comment: @newbie You're welcome. Note that you can skip the `has_key?` business in your code because you can create a `Hash` that has a default value of 0 always by creating it with the `new` constructor: `Hash.new(0)`.

Comment: @newbie `inject` (the last method in the method chain) always returns the last value it processed, which is the `Hash` (`h`) in this case.

Comment: actually i don't understand your code... how did it determine the h is the hashmap and v is the value??... then why is there an h in the end? please explain. thank you.

Comment: See the documentation of `inject` http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject . You call it with an initial value, in this case the hash, and then it will call your block with this initial value and the object from the array we just split. For each loop you have to give it back the `memo` object which you want to use on the next round. That's the `h` at the end.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23292/discussion-between-newbie-and-casper)